# Tkinter how to wrap continuous series of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to GUI programming. So please excuse me if this sounds trivial.

I am doing a project where I have to display images of sign language which correspond to the text I input.

For example, if I input "Hello", it should display images of Sign Language "H" then "E" then "L" and so on side by side.

The problem is in case I input a long text, the images go out of the window and I cannot even scroll horizontally.

I would like it to automatically put images in a new line after the entire width of the screen gets used up.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

aimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("path"))
bimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("path"))
# Similarly, I have cimg, dimg, and so on...

def a():
    apanel = Label(root, image=aimg)
    apanel.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="yes")

def b():
    bpanel = Label(root, image=bimg)
    bpanel.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="yes")
# Similarly, I have functions for all the characters

s = list(input("Enter text here").lower())
for i in s:
    if i == 'a':
        a()
    elif i == 'b':
        b()
    # So on

root.mainloop()
```

Here are some screenshots which might help:

[Image where text is short - fits in the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNleb.png)

[Image where text is long - few characters go out of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQTIp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid` instead of `pack` to achieve what you want.

For example:

```
r,c = 0,0
def a():
    global r,c
    if c==5:
          r+=1
          c=0
    apanel = Label(root, image=aimg)
    apanel.grid(row=r,column=c)
    c+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a responsive grid, and for this you can use the Tkinter's `grid` manager.

Here is one way to do it by setting a maximum length and inserting images in the next row when that length is reached:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

aimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("a.jpg").resize((20, 20)))
bimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("b.jpg").resize((20, 20)))

def a():
    apanel = Label(root, image=aimg)
    apanel.grid(row=r, column=c)

def b():
    bpanel = Label(root, image=bimg)
    bpanel.grid(row=r, column=c)

# Similarly, I have functions for all the characters

s = list(input("Enter text here: ").lower())

r = 0
c = 0
maxc = 10 # max nr. of columns
for i in s:
    if i == 'a':
        a()
    elif i == 'b':
        b()
    c+=1
    if (c==maxc): # when you reach the last column, go to the next row
        c = 0
        r += 1
    # So on


root.mainloop()
```